# django-filter IN lookup filter and list of strings

Tags: python, django, django-filter, graphene-django

Using Graphene in Django to create Gql schema, now trying to filter Foreign Keys with list of strings. It kinda works, but not exactly.

schema.py

```py
class CharInFilter(BaseInFilter, CharFilter):
    pass


class ProductFilter(FilterSet):
    softwares__name = CharInFilter(field_name="softwares__name", lookup_expr="in")

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {"name": ["exact", "icontains"]}


class ProductType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        filterset_class = ProductFilter
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
```

query

```
query authorPageProducts {
  user(slug: "john") {
    productSet(softwares_Name: "Blender") {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          softwares {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what works and what not:

1. softwares_Name: "Blender" -> correct
2. softwares_Name: "Houdini" -> correct
3. softwares_Name: "Blender,Houdini" -> empty result, not correct

I am passing string separated with comma. Can/should I pass list of strings in Gql query? Im not sure if its possible/necessary.

I do have Products that have both Foreign Keys with values "Houdini" and "Blender", so query with "Blender,Houdini" shouldn't be empty.

I tried this query in shell, and its correct. Here I used list of strings.

```py
u = User.objects.get(id=2)
p = u.product_set.filter(softwares__name__in=["Blender", "Houdini"])
```

Here is some info from Django Debug Toolbar, to see SQL expression for third case.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count"
  FROM "shop_product"
 INNER JOIN "shop_product_softwares"
    ON ("shop_product"."id" = "shop_product_softwares"."product_id")
 INNER JOIN "shop_software"
    ON ("shop_product_softwares"."software_id" = "shop_software"."id")
 WHERE ("shop_product"."author_id" = 2 AND "shop_software"."name" IN ('Blender,Houdini'))
```

I cannot figure out where is the issue, while querying with comma separated string, as [docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter) suggest.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon same problem and found a workaround, hope it will help you at least now.
"in" expression in django accepts list, but integration of django-graphene with django-filters accepts only strings in CharFilter and most of other filters. What I did is wrote a custom filter and passed it to FilterSet. In your case it will look like this:

```
def in_filter_method(queryset, field_name, value):
    if value:
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{f'{field_name}__in': json.loads(value)})
    return queryset 

class ProductFilter(FilterSet):
    softwares__name = django_filters.Filter(field_name='softwares__name', method=in_filter_method)
```

And in GraphQL query you should pass json encoded list of values, like "["Blender","Houdini"]"